# Spy movie where recruits are tested by flooding their dormitory

Tags: identify-this-movie, action, spy-movie

There was a movie I watched a couple of years ago, I can not remember the name of it but I remember the following:

- There was middle aged man who had a watch with the ability to shoot darts from the side of it
- There was a scene where the other recruits were sharing the same room as each other (male and female together) and the room started to fill with water suddenly.
- One guy said to the others to keep calm and do what they had been trained to do and so the rest of them barring him went to the showers or something and pulled poles off them and jammed the poles down the toilets for air
- When the room had fully filled with water, the guy I mentioned above had swum to the door to try and open it but failed
- after this attempt, he swims across the room and over the others who are trying to breathe air from the toilets and heads to the mirror window and starts punching it.
- The window starts to break causing their assessor on the other side to move aside from the window and then the window breaks.
- everyone from inside is swept out of the room with the current of the water.
- They are given an assessment on how they did and they are told by the assessor to next time remember to include everyone, this causes the recruits to look into the room and see the drowned body of a girl on a bed or bench
- another scene I remember is where the recruits have to choose a dog each and when they do they have to (I think) explain why they chose that dog.

That is all I remember, please help me out with it, I want to watch it again.
Thanks guys.

Comment: I'm surprised "There was a scene in a church" wasn't the first item in your list of memories!

Comment: I saw this on the HNQ after just having finished watching it, showed up, hoping to answer it, but to no avail!

Comment: Yeah, that was all I remembered from it :), I literally could not remember anything else from the movie.

Answer (score 74, accepted):

You're looking for [Kingsman: The Secret Service](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt2802144/)

> A spy organization recruits an unrefined, but promising street kid into the agency's ultra-competitive training program, just as a global threat emerges from a twisted tech genius.

Here's the scene you're describing

Comment: Fantastic movie, and the sequel is coming out soon: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6Nxc-3WpMbg

Comment: I agree that it is a very good movie. I had zero expectations and was struck by an entertaining, fast-paced movie with nice over-the-top action scenes and funny dialogue.

Comment: FYI, this is actually how things are done in Britain. Oxfords old boy, not Brogues.